# 'While' loop one-liner

Tags: python, while-loop

Is it possible to have a Python *while* loop purely on one line? I've tried this:

```
while n<1000:if n%3==0 or n%5==0:rn+=n
```

But it produces an error message: *Invalid Syntax* at the `if` statement.

Comment: Why don't you *try* it? That is a infinite loop, but it'll work as far as Python is concerned.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have, it doesn't work

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a problem description. *What* doesn't work? What did you expect to happen, what happened instead? What error did you get?

Comment: You can't have nested control structures on one line.

Comment: Right, *that* doesn't work. Complex statements need new lines.

Comment: please don't do this, if you haven't read it  http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ please do, python takes code clarity very serious `Readability counts.`

Answer (score 25):

When using a [compound statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html) in python (statements that need a suite, an indented block), and that block contains *only [simple statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html)*, you can remove the newline, and separate the simple statements with `;` semicolons.

However, that does *not* support compound statements.

So:

```
if expression: print "something"
```

works, and so does using multiple simple statements:

```
while expression: print("something"); print("something else")
```

but:

```
while expression: if expression: print "something"
```

does *not* because both the `while` and `if` statements are compound.

For your *specific* example, you can replace the `if expression: assignment` part with a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), so by using an expression instead of a complex statement:

```
while expression: target = true_expression if test_expression else false_expression
```

in general, or `while n<1000: rn += n if not (n % 3 and n % 5) else 0` specifically.

From a style perspective, you generally want to leave that one line on it's own, though.

Comment: Slightly related, is there any statement equivalent to `?:` C statement in Python ? IF there is, it should do the job.

Comment: @AshRj there is, see my answer.

Comment: @AshRj: Yes, the conditional expression `true_expression if expression else false_expression`.

Comment: Ten years too late, I know, but those are colons, not semicolons.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: no, I'm talking about `;` semicolons here, not `:` colons, when *separating simple statements*. E.g. you can do `print('foo'); print('bar')` in Python, because calling an expression statement is a simple statement. I also talk about *compound* statements, and these use `:` colons.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: I've expanded the answer to include an example using multiple simple staments to illustrate.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood.  I should shut up when it comes to languages that I don't regularly use.  Please accept my apologies, Martijn.  For what it's worth, I do feel your answer is better now.

Answer (score 5):

In your example, you try to collapse two levels of blocks / indentation into a single line, which is not allowed. You can only do this with simple statements, not loops, if statements, function definitions etc. That said, for your example there is a workaround using the ternary operator:

```
while n < 1000: rn += n if (n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0) else 0
```

which reads as 'add n to rn if the condition holds, else add 0'.

Answer (score 1):

It is posible to do something similar:

```
rn = 100
for n in range(10): rn += n if (n%3==0 or n%5==0) else 0
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. What is the gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15185872/edit), not here in comments (but ******************** ***without*** ******************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).