# How come it is wrong to write "for" after "import os;"

Tags: python

I'm using Windows 7 with official Python 2.7 .

On CMD command line, I can write

```
python -c "import os; print os.environ['PATH'].split(';');"
```

However, this is wrong:

```
C:\>python -c "import os; for p in os.environ['PATH'].split(';'): print p"
  File "<string>", line 1
    import os; for p in os.environ['PATH'].split(';'): print p
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could someone please help me out? I really hope to write `import` and subsequent statements in one line, because I'd like to write a doskey command like this, to make a easy-to-read PATH listing:

```
doskey lpath=python -c "import os; for p in os.environ['PATH'].split(';'): print p"
```

Comment: Is it illegal in windows to have linebreaks in a string on the command line?

Comment: @Kay Either that, or at least impossible to enter. (There is no way of doing `$'\n'`...)

Comment: As for the *why*, see [While loop one-liner](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185746)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) instead?

```
python -c "for p in __import__('os').environ['PATH'].split(';'): print p"
```

**UPDATE**

Alternative: replacing `;` with newline.

```
python -c "import os; print os.environ['PATH'].replace(';', '\n')"
```

Comment: Another way: `"from __future__ import print_function; import os;print(*os.environ['PATH'].split(';'), sep='\n')"`

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a peculiarity in the language syntax. Observe:

A statement can be either a simple statement or compound statement:

```
stmt: simple_stmt | compound_stmt
```

A simple statement is defined as follows:

```
simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)* [';'] NEWLINE
small_stmt: (expr_stmt | del_stmt | pass_stmt | flow_stmt |
             import_stmt | global_stmt | nonlocal_stmt | assert_stmt)
```

Notice it contains an `import_stmt` (an import statement). Additionally, only simple statements can be chained with `;`.

A compound statement, on the other hand, is:

```
compound_stmt: if_stmt | while_stmt | for_stmt | try_stmt | with_stmt | funcdef | classdef | decorated
```

Therefore the language disallows your for loop (which is syntactically valid on its own) in the same statement with a simple statement.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html?highlight=grammar