# How to compare an array value with another explicit value in python

Tags: python, loops, compare

I want to do something like this

```
while(x<100 for x in someList):
    if someList has a value more than 100
    the loop should end.
```

Comment: have a look on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185746/while-loop-one-liner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will also end the loop when value is greater than 100

```
for x in someList:
    if x > 100:
        break
```

You can try this:

```
i=0
while ((i<len(someList)) and (someList[i] <= 100) ):
  '''Do something'''
  i+=1
```

Comment: I want a one line answer. Something i can add in a loop condition.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use `itertools.takewhile`:

```
for x in takewhile(lambda x: x <= 100, someList):
    print(x)
```

But I think @sinsuren's `break` solution is best. I'd only use `takewhile` when I don't want a loop, for example in `sum(takewhile(lambda x: x <= 100, someList))`.